# Is there a way to change the default, system wide folder color of a Linux Mint’s folder colors?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

Well, I know that the folders’ colors on the Linux Mint (Cinnamon) are supposed to be green, as it makes a connection to the fact of the distro’s flavor.

I am interested in changing the colors of the folder. And all that I can find as a solution is to change the color for individual folders by selecting each folder’s options.

What I really want is to change the color for the whole system at once. Not only because with the said “solution” I'd have to do it one by one, but also, if necessary to reinstall the OS for future reasons it would mean that I'd necessarily have to do it all over again!

Comment: Images would be great, not sure exactly what you're talking about otherwise, directories usually only have names, not colors. You must be using a GUI file manager?

Comment: I see, but what I meant is that the general directory theme for Mint is a green one. In Windows, for instance, the general theme is yellow. You know, if you want to store your photos or other files, you right click and create a folder. It has a color... 

If you want more info still, please, be free to ask and I'll be glad to explain what I meant and even post some imagery :D

And yes, using a GUI file manager. But as said, it is really solved. Thanks for commenting @Xen2050

Answer (score 0):

As per [the answer posted on the Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=289387&p=1603418), the solution is to open the themes window and choose a different icon theme.